# cordova Android Jquery geolocation issue

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, geolocation

I'm trying to use the geolocation plugin in a cordova project.

In the cordova AndroidManifest.xml, i added this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In the cordova config.xml file, i have this:

```
<gap:plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
```

here is my jquery code:

```
function deviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    localStorage.setItem("lat", lat);
    localStorage.setItem("long", lng);
}
function onError(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert(error.message, function() {});
}
```

on another part of my code, i try to get back those informations:

```
        var lt = localStorage.getItem("lat");
        var lg = localStorage.getItem("long");
        if (lt.length === 0 || lg.length === 0) {
            console.log("! empty location");
            navigator.notification.alert("empty location", function() {});
            return false;
        }
```

on the line **if(lt.lenght ===0 || lg.lenght === 0)** i have this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null**

i think that getCurrentPosition is not recognised, but i can't figured out what i should do.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure `getCurrentPosition` has completed before your calls to `localStorage.getItem`?

Comment: localStorage.getItem is call on a click event, and getCurrentPosition on device ready

Comment: Did you check the latitude and longitude get correctly